# Getting something SPECIFIC from Wordpress loop OUT?

Tags: wordpress, select, loops

I'm totally lost :)

I have a loop which outputs:

- POST ITLE
- POST CONTENT
- POST META

And...

In every post I have an image at the beginning of the CONTENT area.

How to get this image ABOVE the title and do something like:

- FIRST IMAGE FROM CONTENT
- POST TITLE
- THE REST OF THE CONTENT
- POST META

?

I have no clue how to get things out of the loop.

I'd love to see some snippet here, I guess I should maybe use wp query, but never did this before.

Thanks a lot.

MY CURRENT LOOP CODE ("stolen" from TwentyTen default Wordpress theme as I'm still learning):

```
/* I WANT TO PUT CONTENT IMAGE HERE AND TAKE IT FROM 6TH LINE OF THE CODE BELOW:*/      
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header>
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                </header>
                        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>') ); ?> /* I WANT TO TAKE FIRST IMAGE FROM HERE BADLY :) :) :) */
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>  

        <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
                <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="entry-utility">
                    <?php if ( count( get_the_category() ) ) : ?>
                        <span class="cat-links">
                            <?php printf( __( '%2$s'), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?>
                            <time><?php the_time('m F Y') ?></time>  
                        </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                        $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
                        if ( $tags_list ):
                    ?>
                        <span class="tag-links">
                            <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Tagged</span> %2$s', 'twentyten' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $tags_list ); ?>
                        </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment'), __( '1 Comment'), __( '% Comments') ); ?></span>
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit'), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-utility -->  
            </article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I know this code isn't perfect, but at this moment I'm just learning and playing :)

Tnks! :)

Comment: Please post your actual loop code so we can give you a usable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was "featured image" function... :)